# Can I know how many remaining storage space in the phone when the app was installed to SD?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

If my app was installed to SD by user, and in Storage Sense, pictures, music, videos, apps and even download stuff all were set to store in SD, can I know how many remaining storage space in the phone?

```
    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("start time:" + DateTime.Now.ToString(@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff"));

        /* Install folder */
        StorageFolder installFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> installFolderList = await installFolder.GetFoldersAsync();
        Debug.WriteLine("installFolderList:" + installFolderList.Count);
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> installFileList = await installFolder.GetFilesAsync();
        Debug.WriteLine("installFileList:" + installFileList.Count);
        ulong installSize = await GetFreeSpace(installFolder);
        Debug.WriteLine("installSize:" + installSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024);

        /* Local folder */
        StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> localFolderList = await localFolder.GetFoldersAsync();
        Debug.WriteLine("localFolderList:" + localFolderList.Count);
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> localFileList = await localFolder.GetFilesAsync();
        Debug.WriteLine("localFileList:" + localFileList.Count);
        ulong localSize = await GetFreeSpace(localFolder);
        Debug.WriteLine("localSize:" + localSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024);

        /* Local cache folder */
        StorageFolder localCacheFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalCacheFolder;
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> localCacheFolderList = await localCacheFolder.GetFoldersAsync();
        Debug.WriteLine("localCacheFolderList:" + localCacheFolderList.Count);
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> localCacheFileList = await localCacheFolder.GetFilesAsync();
        Debug.WriteLine("localCacheFileList:" + localCacheFileList.Count);
        ulong localCacheSize = await GetFreeSpace(localCacheFolder);
        Debug.WriteLine("localCacheSize:" + localCacheSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024);

        /* Temporary folder */
        StorageFolder tempFolder = ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder;
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> tempFolderList = await tempFolder.GetFoldersAsync();
        Debug.WriteLine("tempFolderList:" + tempFolderList.Count);
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> tempFileList = await tempFolder.GetFilesAsync();
        Debug.WriteLine("tempFileList:" + tempFileList.Count);
        ulong tempSize = await GetFreeSpace(tempFolder);
        Debug.WriteLine("tempSize:" + tempSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024);

        /* Picture folder */
        StorageFolder picFolder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> picFolderList = await picFolder.GetFoldersAsync();
        Debug.WriteLine("picFolderList:" + picFolderList.Count);
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> picFileList = await picFolder.GetFilesAsync();
        Debug.WriteLine("picFileList:" + picFileList.Count);
        ulong picSize = await GetFreeSpace(picFolder);
        Debug.WriteLine("picSize:" + picSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024);

        /* CameraRoll folder */
        StorageFolder cameraRollFolder = KnownFolders.CameraRoll;
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> cameraRollFolderList = await cameraRollFolder.GetFoldersAsync();
        Debug.WriteLine("cameraRollFolderList:" + cameraRollFolderList.Count);
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> cameraRollFileList = await cameraRollFolder.GetFilesAsync();
        Debug.WriteLine("cameraRollFileList:" + cameraRollFileList.Count);
        ulong cameraRollSize = await GetFreeSpace(cameraRollFolder);
        Debug.WriteLine("cameraRollSize:" + cameraRollSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024);

        /* Music folder */
        StorageFolder musicFolder = KnownFolders.MusicLibrary;
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> musicFolderList = await musicFolder.GetFoldersAsync();
        Debug.WriteLine("musicFolderList:" + musicFolderList.Count);
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> musicFileList = await musicFolder.GetFilesAsync();
        Debug.WriteLine("musicFileList:" + musicFileList.Count);
        ulong musicSize = await GetFreeSpace(musicFolder);
        Debug.WriteLine("musicSize:" + musicSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024);

        /* Videos folder */
        StorageFolder videosFolder = KnownFolders.VideosLibrary;
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> videoFolderList = await videosFolder.GetFoldersAsync();
        Debug.WriteLine("videoFolderList:" + videoFolderList.Count);
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> videoFileList = await videosFolder.GetFilesAsync();
        Debug.WriteLine("videoFileList:" + videoFileList.Count);
        ulong videosSize = await GetFreeSpace(videosFolder);
        Debug.WriteLine("videosSize:" + videosSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024);

        Debug.WriteLine("end time:" + DateTime.Now.ToString(@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff"));
    }

    public static async Task<ulong> GetFreeSpace(IStorageItem sf)
    {
        var properties = await sf.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();
        var filteredProperties = await properties.RetrievePropertiesAsync(new[] { "System.FreeSpace" });
        var freeSpace = filteredProperties["System.FreeSpace"];
        return (ulong)freeSpace;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that would be available, as if the User had set everything to SD (music, Apps, pictures ...), then you don't have access to any folder from Phone and User doesn't want any file to be copied/installed on Phone.

Comment: Can you check the files that you got back from the library to see if one of them is on the internal storage? Then you would be able to get the free space I think.

Comment: After studying this issue for a long time, I can't find a StorageFolder-obj belongs to Phone through public API if everything were set to SD. :(

Comment: The more two things to try would be: enumerate the pictures library, there should be 2 CameraRoll folders one internal and one external. If not check for sample pictures, they will be internal, it isn't pretty, but it might work.

Comment: Thanks Adam, I tried your solution, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making an answer from the comment above:

Enumerate the pictures library, there should be 2 CameraRoll folders one internal and one external. Use

```
StorageFolder.Path
```

and check if the path starts with C:\ to see if the folder is the internal or external one [as shown here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23672320/how-to-know-one-storagefolder-obj-belongs-to-sd-or-phone/23672610?noredirect=1#comment36396952_23672610)

Comment: +1 but I'm not sure if it will work if the user had also set 'new pictures' to SD and had deleted 'old' ones.

Comment: As long as they started with the photos pointed at internal storage or moved it there at all it will work. The folder is a lot harder to remove than the images themselves. The only way to get rid of the folder would be through another app, there is no build in way to delete it that I know of.

Comment: I agree that it would be a very rare case. I thought about deleting not by other App, but with a use of computer, when Phone is connected via USB.