# How to know one StorageFolder-obj belongs to SD or Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

Is there have way to know a StorageFolder-obj belongs to SD or Phone on WP8.1? Thanks you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it for example by checking the [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefolder.path.aspx) of `StorageFolder` (or `StorageFIle`):

```
string folderPath = yourStorageFolder.Path;
if (folderPath.StartsWith("C:")) // on Phone
else // on SD Card
```

- if it begins with `D:` (or other letter - not `C:`) - it means it belongs to SD card,
- if it begins with `C:` - it exists on Phone,

EDIT - as Adam has said in comments - it may be more suitable to check first if file is on the Phone, in case the System had assigned other letter than `D:` for SD card.

Comment: Note this may not always work on the emulator. It is safer to use if (folderPath.StartsWith("C:")) // on Phone else //on SD. There is a chance the SD card could get mounted as E: on the emulator.

Comment: @Adam Good point - System probably gives the first free letter for SD card, but your proposal makes the solution safer - just in case other letter was assigned. Thanks.