# Is WP Silverlight 8.1 application installed on SD card or on internal phone memory?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have a Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 C# project.

I know that user can chose where to install new store applications or he/she can move the application from SD to phone and vice versa.

I also know that I can opt in the package.appxmanifest to restrict SD card installation, but this seems to be available only for Windows Phone 8.1 projects.

Anyhow, I would like to check at run-time if the application was installed on SD card or on internal phone memory.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.applicationmodel.package.installedlocation.aspx is this what you want?

Comment: Also [this question may help](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23672320/2681948).

Comment: Thanks, both of you (Malavos and Romasz) pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Romasz was closer, my bad, the question was already answered. And it worth to mention that on Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 you have to set manually to true the SDOptOut attribute from WMAppManifest.xml App element in order to force the installation to the phone memory. This link (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn655124(v=vs.105).aspx) seems to say differently, which is not working.